# Arrange use imports in PhpStorm by string length and not alphabetically

Tags: phpstorm, editorconfig

i need to arrange use imports in PhpStorm by string length and not alphabetically, either in PhpStorm or in the `.editorconfig` file.

So when i do auto format it will not look like:

```
use App\Account\User;
use App\Customer\Gu;
use Laravel\Cashier\Subscription;
```

I need it to do this

```
use App\Customer\Gu;
use App\Account\User;
use Laravel\Cashier\Subscription;
```

Comment: AFAIK -- not possible (especially with `.editoconfig` files -- it's not their job to have such instructions). A-Z order is the most common and what almost everyone seems to be using. You need to file a Feature Request to the [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI).

Comment: **P.S.** In meantime you can use **String manipulation plugin** to make such ordering (manually, of course).